# Assigning colours to factor values in ggplot2 doesn't work

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors

I keep struggling with manually assigning colours to values in ggplot2. What is the easiest way to assign colours manually ignoring alphabetical order?

Here's my data frame with a `colours` column representing the desired colour for each `Status` :

```
    summary_count <– structure(list(Status = structure(c(4L, 6L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("Compromise", 
"Launched", "Not yet rated", "Promise broken", "Promise kept", 
"Stuck"), class = "factor"), n = c(15L, 4L, 4L, 7L, 9L, 21L), 
    total = c(60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60), colours = c("#B71C1C", 
    "#F57F17", "#2196F3", "#0D47A1", "#4CAF50", "#9E9E9E")), .Names = c("Status", 
"n", "total", "colours"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

And my ggplot code:

```
summary_count %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Status, y = n, fill = Status)) +
  geom_col() +
  coord_flip() +
  geom_text(aes(label = n), 
            hjust = 1.5,
            colour = "white",
            fontface = "bold",
            size = 3) +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = rev(order)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = summary_count$colours) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "null")
```

[image]

`Promise broken` should be red, `Stuck` should be Orange and so on...

Comment: use scale_identity http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_identity.html

Comment: Thanks for using `dput`, but there seems to be a syntax error, maybe a missing `(`. Could you doublecheck that?

Comment: Also, to get @wibeasley suggestion to work, you need to set `fill = colours` in your `aes` call

Comment: Data frame generated from `dput` should be good now.

Comment: Nice `scale_identity` totally worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than `scale_fill_identity`, I would recommend creating a named vector to use with `scale_fill_manual`. This way you don't need the color column in your data frame.

```
fill_colors = as.character(summary_count$colours)
names(fill_colors) = summary_count$Status

ggplot(summary_count, aes(x = Status, y = n, fill = Status)) +
  geom_col() +
  coord_flip() +
  geom_text(aes(label = n), 
            hjust = 1.5,
            colour = "white",
            fontface = "bold",
            size = 3) +
  #scale_x_discrete(limits = rev(order)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = fill_colors) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "null")
```

I commented out the `scale_x_discrete` line since you didn't share the `order` variable.